# Which one sounds more natural: "is there any difference" or "are there any differences"?

Tags: difference

"is there any difference between ..." or "are there any differences between ...", which one sound more natural? I searched both in Google Books and both have a lot of results.

Comment: Both 'sound natural'. The first asks about uncountable difference (the fact of being different) and the second asks about countable differences.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey could you give me an example of what uncountable difference and countable difference are? I'm sorry I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a singular form when we mean or expect one difference. This could be a difference of nature.

Is there a/any difference between these balls?
*One is red and the other blue*
*One is wooden and the other made of rubber*

Is there a/any difference between these two ropes?
*One is thicker than the other.

One is made of nylon, and the other is made of natural fibre.*

We use a plural form when we expect that there are (or may be) multiple differences.

Are there any differences between these pictures?
*One has more people, fewer cars, and a cloudier sky than the other.*

Are there any differences between these models of the same car?
*One has air conditioning, a radio, and heated seats. The other does not, and is cheaper*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael! So for the same question, if the questioner is expecting only one difference, he can use "is there a difference". If he is expecting multiple differences, he can use "are there any differences", even if there is actually only one difference, right?

Comment: If the questioner is unsure which form to use, they can use either form.

Comment: Thank you! Btw, is *is there any difference between* correct? I noticed you are using *is there a difference...*. But I found a lot of "is there any difference" use cases in Google Books. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is%20there%20any%20difference%20between%22

Comment: You can use either.